# Input field animation problem after filling the details

Tags: html, css, css-animations, user-input

Hey everyone hope you all doing great, I am looking for some help with css part for my reactjs application input fields. Can someone solve it for me.

My Problem is that I want to make an animated input field in a way that the placeholder will indicate the input details, so on focusing to the input field the placeholder will move to the top of input field and I will be able to fill the details. But after focusing the pointer outside the input field after filling the details the placeholder gets overlapped. How can I solve the problem of removing it from overlapping.

**Here are the images for reference**
[image: This is after focusing on input field]
[image: This is after filling the input field]
[image: This is the problem after focusing outside the input field]

This is **App.js**:

```
<input className='input_field' type="number" name="number" placeholder=''
                                autoComplete='off'
                                value={formValues.number}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                style={{width:"180px",height:"35px"}}
                        />
 <label className='input_label'>Mobile Number</label>
```

This is the corresponding **App.css**:

```
.input_field{
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.input_label{
  position: absolute;
  left: 605px;
  top: 296px;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.input_field:focus{
  border-color: crimson;
}
.input_field:focus + .input_label{
  top: 275px;
  transition: 0.3s;
  color: crimson;
}
```

I have tried adding this

```
.input_field:valid + .input_label
```

along with

```
.input_field:focus + .input_label{
      top: 275px;
      transition: 0.3s;
      color: crimson;
    }
```

but nothing is changed

Can someone please help me solving the problem I faced?

Answer (score 1):

```css
.input_field{
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
  outline: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.input_label{
  position: absolute;
  left: 20px;
  top: 20px;
  pointer-events: none;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.input_field:focus{
  border-color: crimson;
}
.input_field::placeholder {
  color: #fff;
  opacity: 1; /* Firefox */
}

.input_field:-ms-input-placeholder { 
 color: #fff;
}

.input_field::-ms-input-placeholder { 
 color: #fff;
}
.input_field:not(:placeholder-shown) ~ label {
      top: 275px;
      transition: 0.3s;
      color: crimson;
}
```

```html
<input className='input_field' type="number" name="number" placeholder='enter number'
                                autoComplete='off'
                                value={formValues.number}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                style={{width:"180px",height:"35px"}}
                        />
 <label className='input_label'>Mobile Number</label>
```

//You have to add placeholder text and try below css

Comment: Your answer was very helpful thank you so much @Hardik Trada